# Getting to the origin of data in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

What's a consistent way to find the origin of data from a certain web app?

Context:
I'm working on a native app, and am trying to capture data from a publicly hosted JavaScript app. But I can't figure out where exactly the data I'm looking for originates from. The Document Object Model is quite chaotic.

Consider:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and consider `app.js`:

```
// super complex app starts here
var hello = "hello world";
document.write(hello);
// super complex app ends here
```

Let's say `app.js` is a super complex compressed JS app, that somehow writes "hello world" to the document but we have no immediate idea where it's coming from...

What's a definitive way to figure out where `"hello world"` first gets mentioned to the DOM?

Web inspector seems unable to search all downloaded files for "hello world"...

Comment: You want to see the code of web application of which you don't have access to the code base?

Comment: I want to see where the app gets its data from.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+SHIFT+F in webinspector to search in all files?

Comment: Data comes from DataBase it usually doesn't come from JavaScript code.

Comment: data can come from a lotta places @onetwo12

Comment: @ztom omg I can't believe this! I was never aware it was possible to search all files!

Comment: @ztom - sounds like you could turn that comment into an answer and TD540 might be marking it as the selected solution!

Comment: Yeah I would! @ztom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to search in the browser console in all scripts.

Under the corresponding tab (firefox: debugger, chrome: sources) the search field opens with the shortcut:

`CTRL+SHIFT+F`

Answer (score 2):

Using the Chrome Dev Tools, you can do the following:

1. Navigate to the **Elements** panel
2. Right-click the `<body/>` tag and select **Break on... > subtree modifications**
   [image: Picture of the Chrome devtools, with the body tag hovered and right-clicked; the context menu is open and the cursor is hovering "subtree modifications" in the "break on..." submenu]
3. Refresh the page

Now every time the contents of the `<body/>` element is modified by JavaScript, the Chrome Devtools will pause as though there is a breakpoint set on the line that is making the modification.

One caveat: if the source is minified without source maps, you can try "pretty printing" it by clicking the "**{}**" icon in the lower-left of the sources code view, but even that may be of limited value; reading minified code can be anywhere from difficult to impossible.

[image: Chrome devtools sources view opened, with the pretty print icon in the lower-left corner pointed to with a large red arrow]